# Элемент вывода javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Какой элемент нужно использовать для вывода информации пользователю? TextField использую в настоящее время, но он не подходит, так как позволяет вводить информацию (хочется что бы даже копирование из элемента вывода было запрещено).

Comment: Label не подойдет?

Comment: У `TextField` вроде есть свойство `disable` при котором этот элемент просто отображается, но редактирование и копирование невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно подметил товарищ [Duoxx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/245150/duoxx), [Label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) отлично подходит под описание того, что вам нужно.